# Bivariate shape preserving spline

Tags: least-squares, spline

Are there shape preserving (ensuring properties such as convexity, monotonicity, positivity) splines (such as bi-cubic polynomial) in 2 or more dimensions for fitting data in either $l^2$ or $l^1$ norm? It would be great if the objective function for minimizing error is convex.

Comment: I think small regularizing terms for higher order differentials can go a long way.

Comment: @mathreadler: Even if the regularizing weight for the higher order differential is zero, it does not guarantee the positivity of the higher order derivative.